# Model to add two numbers using machine learning

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm trying to use machine learning to model an addition. But the model always predicts the same. Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import random
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

X=np.array([[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,3],[3,4],[4,4],[4,5]])
Y=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X,Y)
x=random.random()
y=random.random()
d=1
e=10000
accuracy=0
while d<e:
    d+=1
    if (clf.predict([[x, y]])) == x+y:
        accuracy+=1
    if d==e:
        print(accuracy)
```

In 10000 predictions zero predicted Y is and addition of both random variables in X what went wrong.

Comment: You're trying to apply a classifier to a regression problem. That's not going to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, as pointed out in the comments, this is a regression problem, not a classification one, and `GaussianNB` is a classifier. Secondly, your code is wrong, you're predicting on the same test set, since you're not regenerating the random values to predict on.

Here's a how you could go about solving this problem. First of all, you're trying to model a linear relation between the features and the target variable, hence you want your model to learn how to map `f(X)->y` with a linear function, in this case a simple addition. Hence you need a [linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_model).

So here we could use [`LinearRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html). To train the regressor you could do:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = np.random.randint(0,1000, (20000, 2))
y = X.sum(1)
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X,y)
```

And then similarly generate a *test* test with unseen combinations, which hopefully the regressor should be able to accurately predict on:

```
X_test = X = np.random.randint(0,1000, (2000, 2))
y_test = X.sum(1)
```

If we predict with the trained model, and compare the predicted values with the orginal ones, we see that the model indeed perfectly maps the addition function as we expected it to:

```
y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)

pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([y_test, y_pred]).T, columns=['Test', 'Pred']).head(10)

    Test    Pred
0  1110.0  1110.0
1   557.0   557.0
2    92.0    92.0
3  1210.0  1210.0
4  1176.0  1176.0
5  1542.0  1542.0
```

By checking the model's `coef_`, we can see that the model has learnt the following optimal coefficients:

```
lr.coef_
# array([1., 1.])
```

And:

```
lr.intercept_
# 4.547473508864641e-13 -> 0
```

Which basically *turns* a linear regression into an addition, for instance:

```
X_test[0]
# array([127, 846])
```

So we'd have that `y_pred = 0 + 1*127 + 1*846`

Answer (score 3):

the `random.random()` generate real number random between 0 and 1, so model just predicted 0 or 1 and maximum 2, and x+y  is not an integer.

you can use of `random.randint(a,b)`

```
x=random.randint(0,4)
y=random.randint(1,5)
```